# Error on connect mssql with codeigniter - odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I want to connect CodeIgniter with MSSQL and after get lot of search and get some links for its connection and I followed this [link](https://futbolsalas15.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/7-steps-to-make-sql-server-and-codeigniter-works/).

But when I try to run application it gives:

> odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'., SQL state 28000 in SQLConnect

And also when I tried to connect with core PHP it works, I don't know where the actual problem is.

Comment: No driver `sqlsrv` found on database load. enable the `php_sqlsrv` dll in your extention

Comment: This is already done, but when using core php on same machine its working fine, The problem is only with codeigniter

Comment: Have you restarted you apache after adding the dll

Comment: yes i had restarted